# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

Hello guys I'm trying to create a function to get the full link if it has #mystring is exists
for example

> [www.mydomian.com/#mystring&........](http://www.mydomian.com/#mystring&........).

but when I split it shows me errors

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "split", data[1] is
> undefined

```
   function my_function() {

      var link = window.location +''; // get website link as string www.mydomain.com

      var data = link.split("#");  // start link after # for example www.mydomain.com/#mystring&anotherstring=hello
      
      var widget_type = data[1].split("&")[0]; // to get "mystring" 


         if(widget_type == 'mystring') { // check if "mystring" in the link exists
           var link = window.location.hash.substr(1); // get full link
            console.log(link)
         }
   
      
   }
   my_function();
```

so how can i check if "#mystring" is exits in my link before do it and fix split error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `link` doesn't contain `#`, the `data` array after splitting will contain only one item which is the `link`, So you need to check if there is a second item in the `data` by optional chaining after `data[1]`

```
var widget_type = data[1]?.split("&")[0]
```

Or you can use `if` condition.

```
const path = data[1]

var widget_type = '';

if (path) {
   widget_type = path.split("&")[0]; 
}
```